# Algorithm to Detect Disjunctive Relationships

Tags: algorithms, logic

I'm working with logic formulas of the form '0 & 2 | 0 & 3'. I was wondering if anyone knew of an algorithm that would take in such a formula, detect existing disjunctive relationships, and return a simplified version.

For instance, in this case, the algorithm should return '0 & (2|3)'.

Ideally, the algorithm should be able to handle more complex inputs.

Comment: "logic formula"? Do you mean expressions with bitwise operations? Please explain why and how '0 & 2 | 0 & 3' is simplified to '0 & (2|3)'. In all popular programming languages, '&' has a higher priority than '|', whether as bitwise operators or logical operators.

Comment: Please define your notation.  I don't know what the notation '0 & 2 | 0 & 3' means.  Are you asking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form?  Please explain what you mean by "disjunctive relationships" and what it means to "detect" them.  It sounds like you want an algorithm to do something; what is the input to the algorithm, and what is the desired output?